# Using stored procedures from AX

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, axapta

What are the Pros and Cons for calling stored procedure from AX 2009?

Is it recommended as per Microsoft Standard?

Answer (score 4):

It depends.  I would say it is not recommended traditionally to use stored procedures except to communicate with other external systems.  And even in those scenarios, you should consider the AIF if possible.  Again, these pros/cons all *depend* on the purpose of the SP.

**Pros:**

- Speed
- Easy access to other external databases
- Familiarity for primarily SQL developers

**Cons:**

- Typically bypasses AX security (depends on the SP)
- Bypasses business logic when used against an AX database. An update/delete/etc to an AX table will not fire the record/field validation or any update/delete/insert logic
- Lose visibility in AX (A developer may have admin rights in AX, but no permissions in SQL)
- Can bypass transaction scope for what is expected to be an atomic business process (ttsbegin/ttscommit). The business transaction may be aborted and rolled back, but the SP may not.
- Makes debugging more difficult (visibility)
- Doesn't easily allow for future development. For example, a SP that periodically updates AX Customers may be running, then a new developer wants to put code on the AX table to update Contacts when a customer changes...his code won't be run.

**EDIT:** Direct SQL calls would be better than stored procedures if absolutely needed.  Direct SQL is sometimes used in AX 2009 and can be seen in `\Classes\InventUnusedDimCleanUp`

Answer (score 2):

It's **not** recommended at all. Surely will drive into future problems for maintenance. It will ignore or duplicate (or both) business logic that will be better maintained (and even found) by an AX developer who will never look for code on the database.

Only recommended as a big exception for processes that breaks the server performance when developed following best practices, and after trying to optimize this development in any way possible without success.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore,
if you create any SQL-objects referencing AX-objects with schemabinding , no more changes can be done in AX anymore.

**Example**: Create a View in SSMS which references an AX table. Use schemabinding to use indices. After that, add a field to the table in AX and try to synchronize. Won't work.

**And**: You won't get any CfMD if you use direct access to DB.